# How can I get the the latitude longitude from touching screen

Tags: ios, gps, ios-simulator

How can I get the latitude and longitude from the touching screen when I am using MkMapView and Google API?

Comment: I'm interesting in this question too. I've tried to get them on each coordinate changing. But I hadn't to set the given coordinates again